# collection of features resulting 50% accuracy, how to explain that?

Tags: probability

If there are 14 peoples, each of them has its own distinct theory base on some fact (there are no correlation between their theory) for predicting tomorrow will it rain or not. each of them do a vote on it, and the majority vote win and make decision of tomorrow will it be rain or not. after one month of predicting the next day weather, the accuracy is average 50% of days in that month is correct. 
Then, what kind of reasoning (for further analysis) I can give out to explain that these 14 theories end up like the probability of flipping a coin?

Comment: Individually are their theories any good at predicting the weather?

Comment: individually their accuracy is better than r squared

Comment: If there are 10^100 people and all you do is a majority vote then single persons who are right all the time, i.e. the signal, will be completely covered by the noise from the rest of random guesses. Yep, majority vote in this case is like flipping a coin

Comment: @Drey if what you said is true, then is it also true that each of them has 50% probability in theory? And if i remove 1 of them each time, i will still get 50%?

Comment: Actually, I think you cannot say a lot about the individual predictors: e.g. you have `n` people which are always is right and `n` which are always wrong and some other random predictors. You will still get a coin flip in the end. You cannot retrieve information about the source from the aggregate. E.g. a mean of 0 can come from any sequence of numbers; be them large or small or however distributed.

Comment: @Drey in his response to my comment Bryan said that individually the voters' accuracies are better than r squared. So it's not that most are random guesses. I'm also curious about what's going on here.

Comment: @Hugh I actually don't understand the relation of r^2 (of which model? or which correlation coefficient) and accuracy. It sounds for me like comparing the material of socks to the speed of wind. Anyhow, what does mean better? better than 0 ? or 0.001 ? I just can't figure out the right information.